# The 'Cast Close and Reopen Votes' privilege page needs to be updated

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons, privileges, documentation

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) contains the following image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m7UPm.png]

It should be updated to a new one since the closing reasons changed

Update: The problem also exists in [this page about flagging](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts). Also in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes) about viewing close votes.

Comment: Side Note: This has already been fixed in meta.

Answer (score 1):

These pages were all up-to-date when I checked them. Just leaving this answer so the bug doesn't stay unresolved. :)